# Comparing two datasets to determine correlation

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, data.table, bioinformatics

In process of comparing the two (sample) datasets below I'm attempting to find the correlation of matches per column (ignoring the NA's). I know I can do this in a nested for loop, but this would make the process too slow, and I'm uncertain how to do this vectorized/ in data.table.

```
adf <- structure(c(NA, "CT", NA, "CT", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GG", NA, "CT", NA, "TC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "AG", NA, "TT", NA, "TC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GG", NA, "CT", NA, "TC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GG", NA, "CT", NA, "CC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "AG", NA, "CT", NA, "CC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "AG", NA, "TT", NA, "CC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "AG", NA, "CT", NA, "TC", NA, "GG", NA, "CC", NA, "GG", NA, "TT", NA, "TC", NA, "GG", NA, "CC", NA, "AG", NA, "TT", NA, "TT", NA, "GG", NA, NA, NA, "GG"), .Dim = c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(     c("7:100014471", "7:100038150", "7:100056646", "7:100079759",     "7:100103260", "7:100129337", "7:100145085", "7:100195980",     "7:100227528", "7:100256942"), c("100099681", "101666591",     "102247652", "102284616", "103582612", "104344528", "105729734",     "109897137", "112768301", "114724443")))
tdf <- structure(c(NA, "CC", NA, "CT", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GG", NA, "CT", NA, "TC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "AG", NA, "TT", NA, "TC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GG", NA, "CT", NA, "TC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GG", NA, "CT", NA, "CC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "AG", NA, "CT", NA, "CC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "AG", NA, "TT", NA, "CC", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "AG", NA, "CT", NA, "TC", NA, "GG", NA, "CC", NA, "GG", NA, "TT", NA, "TC", NA, "GG", NA, "CC", NA, "AG", NA, "TT", NA, "TT", NA, "GG", NA, NA, NA, "GG"), .Dim = c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(     c("7:100014471", "7:100038150", "7:100056646", "7:100079759",     "7:100103260", "7:100129337", "7:100145085", "7:100195980",     "7:100227528", "7:100256942"), c("100099681", "101666591",     "102247652", "102284616", "103582612", "104344528", "105729734",     "109897137", "112768301", "114724443")))

tdf[1:10, 1:10]
#            100099681 101666591 102247652 102284616 103582612 104344528 105729734 109897137 112768301 114724443
#7:100014471 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100038150 "CC"      "CT"      "TT"      "CT"      "CT"      "CT"      "TT"      "CT"      "TT"      "TT"     
#7:100056646 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100079759 "TC"      "TC"      "TC"      "TC"      "CC"      "CC"      "CC"      "TC"      "TC"      "TT"     
#7:100103260 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100129337 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        "GG"      "GG"      "GG"     
#7:100145085 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100195980 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        "CC"      "CC"      NA       
#7:100227528 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100256942 "GG"      "AG"      "GG"      "GG"      "AG"      "AG"      "AG"      "GG"      "AG"      "GG"     

adf[1:10, 1:10]
#            100099681 101666591 102247652 102284616 103582612 104344528 105729734 109897137 112768301 114724443
#7:100014471 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100038150 "CT"      "CT"      "TT"      "CT"      "CT"      "CT"      "TT"      "CT"      "TT"      "TT"     
#7:100056646 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100079759 "TC"      "TC"      "TC"      "TC"      "CC"      "CC"      "CC"      "TC"      "TC"      "TT"     
#7:100103260 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100129337 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        "GG"      "GG"      "GG"     
#7:100145085 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100195980 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        "CC"      "CC"      NA       
#7:100227528 NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA       
#7:100256942 "GG"      "AG"      "GG"      "GG"      "AG"      "AG"      "AG"      "GG"      "AG"      "GG"
```

My expected output would be something like this, only the correlation row is really needed, but for illustration/clarity I've also added the Matches/Mismatches.

```
          100099681 101666591 102247652 102284616 103582612 104344528 105729734 109897137 112768301 114724443
matches   2         3         3         3         3         3         3         5         5         5
mismatch  1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
cor       0.67      1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use colsums:

```
colSums(adf == tdf, na.rm = TRUE) / 
(
  colSums(adf == tdf, na.rm = TRUE) + 
    colSums(adf != tdf, na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

A bit cleaner version:

```
# cleaner output
matches <- colSums(adf == tdf, na.rm = TRUE) 
mismatches <- colSums(adf != tdf, na.rm = TRUE)
allCnt <- matches + mismatches

# output
data.frame(
  matches,
  mismatches,
  allCnt,
  myCor = matches / allCnt
)

#           matches mismatches allCnt     myCor
# 100099681       2          1      3 0.6666667
# 101666591       3          0      3 1.0000000
# 102247652       3          0      3 1.0000000
# 102284616       3          0      3 1.0000000
# 103582612       3          0      3 1.0000000
# 104344528       3          0      3 1.0000000
# 105729734       3          0      3 1.0000000
# 109897137       5          0      5 1.0000000
# 112768301       5          0      5 1.0000000
# 114724443       4          0      4 1.0000000
```